# powershell array string issues in the loop

Tags: arrays

```
$resources = @()
$resources += "PC1"
$creds =@()

write-host "Obtaining creds from PMP"
for ($i=0; $i -lt $resources.length; $i++)  {
                $creds = get-creds $resources[$i] root
} 

for ($i=0; $i -lt $resources.length; $i++)  {

$sessionA = $(New-SshSession -ComputerName $resources[$i] -Username root -Password $creds[$i])

if ($sessionA -match "Successfully connected") {
x
}
else
{
error
}}
```

I keep getting error trying to establish the ssh connection.
If i echo the values of $resources[0] and $creds[0] I'm getting correct results and can use those values to ssh with putty.
If I create new variables:

```
$tes1 = $resources[0]
$test2 =  $creds[0]
```

and use both in:

```
$sessionA = $(New-SshSession -ComputerName $test1 -Username root -Password $test2)
```

it also works...

For some reason the array references don't :/

thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First you have missed a clossing '}' at the end of your post. And secondly you never add `$pass` to the `$creds` array.

Comment: Sorry it's just part of the code. I replaced $pass with $creds the way it is in my code.

Comment: Still the same :P doesn't like my array string :/

Comment: try to use in the second for loop another variable as counter. So for example try it with: for ($y=0; $y-lt $resources.length; $y++)  {....

Comment: Same again I'm afraid but good though.for ($y=0; $y -lt $resources.length; $y++)  {
    
$sessionA = $(New-SshSession -ComputerName $resources[$y] -Username root -Password $creds[$y])  When i use the same syntax but without referencing array same as above for $test and $test1 the connection is established fine...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it worked with replacing $i with $y for second loop. Thanks.